# Execute if statement everytime when the url hash changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I am using easytab to create my tab page, therefore page won't refresh when switching tab but I'd need to create an function which will hidden some buttons for specific tab.

So for the javascript, i have built a checker for the url hash

```
//hiding 30d/90d/1y button for feed 

var FeedPanelchecker = location.hash;
        if(FeedPanelchecker == "#panel-Feeds"){
            $("#30Days").css("display","none");
            $("#12Weeks").css("display","none");
            $("#12Months").css("display","none");
        }
});
```

But I don't know how to make it excute everytime when the hash tag change, should id use `.change()`? but it seem for input type elements only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use [`onhashchange Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange), *fires when a window's hash changes*

```js
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function() {
  var FeedPanelchecker = location.hash;
  if (FeedPanelchecker == "#panel-Feeds") {
    $("#30Days").css("display", "none");
    $("#12Weeks").css("display", "none");
    $("#12Months").css("display", "none");
  };
});
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the code on easytab after event

```
    $('#tab-full-container').bind('easytabs:after', function() {
    var FeedPanelchecker = location.hash;
            if(FeedPanelchecker == "#panel-Feeds"){
                $("#30Days").css("display","none");
                $("#12Weeks").css("display","none");
                $("#12Months").css("display","none");
            }
    });

})
```

Comment: Is there any documentation that list all easy-tab's API? i can't find this in easytab's official site. Many thanks

Comment: @anson920520 see https://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/#advanced-demo for the event hooks